# Como criar uma ListView em um Navigation Drawer?

Tags: java, android, xml

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1jDi.png)

O meu objetivo é o seguinte: no lugar desses itens que vem por padrão na Navigation Drawer eu gostaria de colocar uma série de Listas que vão se modificar conforme eu crie, exclua e edite essas listas.

Eu tentei criar um Adapter com um Array de Strings apenas para testar (meu objetivo real é usar uma lista de Objetos). Mas não funcionou mesmo assim.

Segue o código:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
  private List<ListaDeCompras> listasDeCompras = new ArrayList<ListaDeCompras>();
  private ListaDeCompras listaDeComprasAtual;
  private ListView listaDeComprasView;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    String[] listas = {"Lista 1", "Lista 2", "Lista 3"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listas);
    listaDeComprasView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listas_de_compras);
    listaDeComprasView.setAdapter(adapter);

  }
}
```

activity_main_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nova_lista"
        android:title="Nova Lista" />
</group>

<item android:title="Listas de Compras">
    <menu>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listas_de_compras"
            />
    </menu>
</item>
```

Comment: Quer seguir o layout predefinido do Navigation Drawer ou quer um layout personalizado por si?

Comment: Vou seguir o layout predefinido.

Answer (score -1):

Acho que o código abaixo pode resolver seu problema.

```
Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();

for (String itemMenu : menus) {
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.add(itemMenu);
    menuItem.setIcon(....);
    menuItem.setTitle(....);
}
```

Segue a documentação abaixo para a classe Menu é MenuItem.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html